# imageView.center CGPointMake animation not working when called from viewDidLoad

Tags: uiview, uiviewanimation, cgpoint

I have an Image View object on the screen, and I've set a method for moving it:

```
- (void)moveImageViewLeft {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    CGFloat cgfltMoveX = 340;

    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x - cgfltMoveX, imageView.center.y);

    [UIView commitAnimations]; }
```

When I call it from let's say a button action or a swipe action, it's working fine:

```
[self moveImageViewLeft];
```

But when I want to do the same under viewDidLoad, nothing happens...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self moveImageViewLeft];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. }
```

Why? 
Can anybody explain me?
How could I solve it?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I've found the solution: I had to disable the option "Use Autolayout"...